# How to make laravel 8 laravel/ui auth multiple different table?

Tags: php, laravel

**Install laravel/ui**

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

*I want to add auth with different table*
**app\auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    
],
```

Comment: It's very simple but a little long in Laravel and you can search about Multi Authentication... read this link https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-multi-auth-authentication-tutorialexample.html   .... if you had a problem with implementing this feature ask your question

Answer (score 2):

**The first step**
**php artisan make:model Admin -m**
until message

- Model created successfully.
  Created Migration: 2020_01_23_022811_create_admins_table *

change the code in the section : database/migrations/2020_01_23_022811_create_admins_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 150);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('phone', 20)->nullable();
            $table->enum('level_access', ['admin', 'superadmin'])->default('admin');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

*and run the command * 
** php artisan migrate **

- then change the code * 
  ** app/Models/Admin.php **

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'phone', 'level_access'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    
    /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token, 'admin.password.reset', 'admins'));
    }
    
}
```

*next*
**php artisan make:controller AuthAdmin/LoginController**
**php artisan make:controller Admin/DashboardController -r**

- then change the code * 
  **app/Http/Controllers/AuthAdmin/LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\AuthAdmin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => ['logout']]);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function showLoginForm() {
        return view('authadmin.login');
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     * @return type
     */
    public function login(Request $request) {
        // Validate the form data
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);
        
        // Attempt to log the user in
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
            // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }
        // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors(['password' => [
                    'These credentials don\'t match our records.', 
                    'Or Incorrect Password'
                ]]);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function logout() {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Admin/DashboardController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

}
```

*Next create a new folder in * 
** resources/views **

1. resources/views/admin
2. resources/views/authadmin

*Next create the **dashboard.blade.php** file in the **admin** folder folder

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Hello, ')  }} {{Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name}}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

*Next create the **login.blade.php** file in the **authadmin** folder folder

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login Admin') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login.submit') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

*Next create the **admin.blade.php** file in the **resources/views/layouts/admin.blade.php** folder folder

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" >

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
                  
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
                            {{-- <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{ __('List Of Question') }}</a>
                            </li> --}}
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('admin.logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="{{asset('dist/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}" ></script>
    <script src="{{asset('dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}" ></script>
    <script src="{{asset('dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*next change the configuration in the file **config/auth.php** *

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],

...

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
    
...

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
```

*change Handler in file : **app/Exceptions/Handler.php** *

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }

    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        
        $guard = \Arr::get($exception->guards(), 0);

        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                $login = 'admin.login';
                break;
            default:
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
}
```

*add route for admin in file : **routes/web.php** *

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {

    /**
     * Login
     */
    Route::get('login', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthAdmin\LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('login', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthAdmin\LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login.submit');

    Route::middleware(['auth:admin'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.dashboard');

        /*
        * Logout
        */
        Route::post('logout/', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthAdmin\LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('admin.logout');
    });
});
```

*add seeder for Admin default data*
**php artisan make:seeder AdminSeeder**
*edit AdminSeeder in file : **database/seeders/AdminSeeder.php** *

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AdminSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $arrayAdmin = [
            [
                'name' => 'Valentino Rossi',
                'email' => 'superadmin@admin.dev',
                'level_access' => 'superadmin',
                'password' => Hash::make('123456'),
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Valentino Rossa',
                'email' => 'admin@admin.dev',
                'level_access' => 'admin',
                'password' => Hash::make('123456'),
            ],
        ];

        foreach($arrayAdmin as $value) {
            Admin::create($value);
        }
    }
}
```

*AND edit DatabaseSeeder in file : **database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php** *

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // \App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();
        $this->call([
            UserSeeder::class,
            AdminSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

*and run the command*
**php artisan migrate:refresh --seed**